# Filtering vector tiles from GeoServer using OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector-tiles

I am using GeoServer, with a Store based on PostGIS, and OpenLayers to manage some vector datas. On GeoServer I have created an SQL view to link a table with geometry and related temporal datas from another table.

**PSEUDO SQL view**

```
select ...
from tab_geometry as a
on tab_no_geometry as b
join a.id = b.tab_geometry_id
```

Using a CQL filter passed from OpenLayers on the WMS I can put my information on the map.

**PSEUDO CQL filter**

```
cql_filter='area_id=X and timestamp=Y'
```

Now I need to convert this workflow from WMS to VectorTiles. With [TileWMS](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileWMS-TileWMS.html) I use params for pass a CQL filter but this attribute is not in [VectorTile](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_VectorTile-VectorTile.html).

What do you suggest as an approach to solve this problem?

Comment: With vector tiles you can filter on the client.  In the same way as this example https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html highlights Africa you could use a style function to show only Africa https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tile-selection-forked-vr7ht?file=/main.js

Comment: @Mike if I filter from the client there are problems related to the number of features from vector tiles? Probably is a my misunderstanding but, using the example of Africa, all the not stylized vectors requires however an amount of band on the client side.

Comment: I've tested with over 20k of polygons. Unfortunatly the "style filter" is very very slow. So, there are the possibility to recreate something like CQL filter for VectorTile?